# Not able to remove the space between navbar and the dropdown menu even after using border : none;

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have space between the nav bar and the dropdown menu. I have to remove that space and insert a line.

Comment: create a jsfiddle link and give to us

Comment: @Rohit Azad, https://jsfiddle.net/ra5dc7x3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.nav>li{border-top:1px solid #444;}
.navbar-collapse{border-top:0;}
}
```

[See demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ra5dc7x3/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to this

```
button.navbar-toggle {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
```

**Because you define your button**

```
padding-top: 2px;
 padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
```

so that show to margin top

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ra5dc7x3/1/)**